# Is it possible to use GoogleFinanceAPI on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, feedparser, google-finance-api

I've been searching around for a definitive answer but have yet to find one. It seems as though the simple answer is "no" because the GoogleAPIs use too many Java classes that aren't included in Android.

If that's the case then I need to ask another question: what is the best way to parse information from "http://www.google.com/finance/" ?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ allows access.  You'll need to get authentication going, then you can use the Atom parser from that lib to parse the feeds.  You should use a SyncAdapter model to cache the data that you fetch through the API.